# Problems passing options in specialized plot functions for Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

This should be quick to an expert, but I'm relatively new at defining functions with options. Here is a schematic of what I've tried, I'll explain after showing the code:

```
MyPlotFunction[params_, optionalparameter_List:{1,2,3}, opts:OptionsPattern[]]:=
    Plot [ stuff, {x,0,1},  Evaluate@FilterRules[{opts},Options@Plot]];

Options[MyPlotFunction] = {  PlotRange->{-5,5}, Frame->True, ... other plot options};
```

There are four slight subtleties:

1. I have an optional parameter in my function that needs to be a list of integers.
2. I want the ability to call the function with any option of Plot, especially using values other than the default values specified in the third line.
3. I want to have default values for some of the options.
4. I potentially want to put other options in the function, so it is not guaranteed that all of the options should be passed through to plot.

But what I have above doesn't work. The default options I set are ignored, yet they appear in the `??MyPlotFunction` information for my function. I'll give examples if you guys can't spot the error yet.

Edit:
Examples that doesn't work:

1. `SimplePlot[t_,opts:OptionsPattern[{PlotRange->{-4,4},Frame->True}]]:=
    Plot[2x+t,{x,0,1},opts];`
   Fails, the default option is ignored.
2. `SimplePlot[t_,opts:OptionPattern[]]:=
    Plot[2x+t],{x,0,1},opts];
    Options[SimplePlot] = {PlotRange->{-4,4},Frame->True};`
   Fails, the default option is ignored.
3. `SimplePlot[t_,opts__:{PlotRange->{-4,4},Frame->True}]:=
    Plot[2x+t,{x,0,1},opts];`
   Default options work with a bare call, but if one of these options or any other plot option is overridden the remaining defaults are lost.

Comment: Can you edit this with more detail. Is params the stuff you are plotting? If so then put it as the argument to plot. If not then where does it go? It might also help if you explain what the optional parameter is supposed to do. Your function doesn;t have a closing "]" but I presume this is a cut and paste error. You will find other discussions on here and Mathgroup about OptionValue, FilterRules and so on that should help you with using options.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`OptionsPattern[]` only catches the options that are passed in, so you need to explicitly include any non-default option settings, say by using something like:

```
FilterRules[{opts, Options[MyPlotFunction]}, Options@Plot]
```

Here's a simple example:

```
Options[MyPlotFunction] = {PlotRange -> {-5, 5}, Frame -> True};

MyPlotFunction[params_, optionalparameter_List: {1, 2, 3}, 
  opts : OptionsPattern[MyPlotFunction]] := 
 Plot[optionalparameter, {x, 0, 1}, 
  Evaluate@FilterRules[{opts, Options[MyPlotFunction]}, Options@Plot]]
```

[image]

Comment: This looks useful, checking it now.

Comment: This works, and works for my application. One part I don't understand though is that it no longer works if I don't filter the options. Take the exact same code and replace Evaluate@FilterFules[{opts,Options[MyPlotFunction]},Options@Plot] with just opts. It looks like your joining the default options to the specified options, and feeding that into plot. How does Plot decide which to use when you feed it to conflicting values for the same option?

Comment: @braydenware The point is not that you *filter* the options, but that you *pass* your default options after `{opts}`, so even in the absense of explicit `{opts}`, you still pass all your default option settings explicitly to `Plot`. This is also why Brett placed them after `{opts}` - so that options explicitly passed in `{opts}` would override those from `Options[MyPlotFunction]` which follow after them.

Comment: @braydenware In case of conflicting option settings with the same option name, the first one encountered is the one that is used.

Comment: @Leonid Excellent comments. I see both of these points in action after testing some code. Is there also a way to have the function "know" All of the options it has available, in the same way that the list returned by Options[Plot] includes the list returned by Options[Graphics]? My original programming language was Java, so it is natural for me to try to "extend" Plot and Animate to my special applications (which are animations of plots of waves in various scenarios).

Comment: @braydenware I think that would be an excellent separate question, since the answer has a subtle point or two.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments to Brett's answer, since options given first supersede options given later, and since options to Plot may be given as a list, you can write something like this:

```
Options[SimplePlot] = {PlotRange -> {-4, 4}, Frame -> True};

SimplePlot[t_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
  Plot[2 x + t, {x, 0, 1}, opts, #] & @ Options[SimplePlot];
```